# Wordpress Custom Field Output is Not Hyperlinked. Anyway to do the Same?

Tags: wordpress, field, custom-fields

I'm using wordpress custom field called company_name at the end of the post to display company name. I'm able to display the value of custom field but the output coming is not hyperlinked like wordpress categories.

What I want is when visitor click on the company name wordpress should show all posts related to that company.

I don't want to use wordpress categories for this. Can anyone help me pls with custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but here's what I would do with how you described what you want:

1. Tag each relevant post with "Company Name"
2. In custom field, add key/value company_name/Company Name
3. Create a short code [company-name]
4. When you process the short code:

   - Grab the custom field value for company_name
   - wrap the anchor text "Company Name" with a tag link, like this: href="http://mysite.com/tag/company-name">Company Name